# Datatables warning(table id = 'example'): cannot reinitialise data table

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

### Eu estou trabalhando com um exemplo de datatable rowgroup e recebendo um erro como este ao carregamento da página:

> Datatables warning(table id = 'example'): cannot reinitialise data
>   table ##

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "tableProcessa.php",
                    "type": "POST"
                }
            });
        });
        
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                order: [
                    [0, 'asc']
                ],
                rowGroup: {
                    dataSrc: 0
                }
            });
        });
        
    </script>
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="display" id="example" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>OP</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Trabalho</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Obs</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Vc não pode iniciar o datatables duas vezes. Não entendi o motivo de vc estar fazendo isso no mesmo evento ready, embora em blocos separados. Meio sem sentido isso.

Comment: Pq não junta os dois `$('#example').DataTable({` num só?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O próprio log está exibindo o erro "*cannot reinitialise data table*", ou seja, não pode reinicializar o `DataTable`. Inicialize somente uma vez e faça todas as configurações necessárias como no exemplo a seguir.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "tableProcessa.php",
            type: "POST"
        },
        order: [
            [0, 'asc']
        ],
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: 0
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado! consegui resolver o meu problema